# Extract tables from pdf using anchor using Document Understanding in UiPath?

Tags: data-extraction, invoice, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to **extract tables** from pdf files. I am using **UiPath's Document Understanding** for this purpose. I have to create a template for this purpose and then use that template for other similar invoices. The issue I am facing is that the **number of items in the table is varying.** For example some pdf's have table which contain **4 items** whereas other pdf files have table which contain only **1 item**. So if I create a template using the pdf which has a table containing **4 items** then it works. But then the same template when used for files which have table containing **1 item** then it does not properly extract the data in the table. Is there any solution for this?

The solution should be able to extract tables from similar invoices containing **varying number of items** in the table. The **format and layout of the invoice and the table is similar**. The only thing **varying is the number of items** in each table.

Thanks for your time and help!